# How to use cross_val_score with random_state

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I get different values for different runs. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score

X = np.random.random((100,5))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,))
cross_val_score = RandomForestClassifier()
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, random_state=1)
s = cross_val_score(cross_val_score, X, y,scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)
print(s)
# [ 0.42321429  0.44360902  0.34398496]

s = cross_val_score(cross_val_score, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)
print(s)
# [ 0.42678571  0.46804511  0.36090226]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mistake you are making is calling the [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) whose default arg, `random_state` is None. So, it picks up the seed generated by `np.random` to produce the random output.

The `random_state` in both [`StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) and `RandomForestClassifier` need to be the same inorder to produce equal arrays of scores of cross validation.

**Illustration:**

```
X=np.random.random((100,5))
y=np.random.randint(0,2,(100,))

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, random_state=1)        # Setting random_state is not necessary here
s = cross_val_score(clf, X,y,scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)
print(s)
##[ 0.57612457  0.29044118  0.30514706]
print(s)
##[ 0.57612457  0.29044118  0.30514706]
```

Another way of countering it would be to not provide `random_state` args for both RFC and SKF. But, simply providing the `np.random.seed(value)` to create the random integers at the beginning. These would also create equal arrays at the output.

Comment: haha yeah i guess the clue is in the name, it's not called a `DeterministicForestClassifier` is it?!