# How to get the only the scores that we need in classification report in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn `cross_val_score` to get my results as follows.

```
import numpy as np
my_results = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
print(np.mean(my_results))
```

So, this gives me the accuracy of my cross validation. To get my other scores I have to perform the classification again to get the results.

```
precision = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'precision_weighted')
#print(precision.mean())
recall = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'recall_weighted')
#print(recall.mean())
f1 = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'f1_weighted')
#print(f1.mean())
```

I am only interested in the `accuracy, weighted average precision, weighted average recall, weighted avareage f-measure and auc` and want to get these scores by only performing `cross_val_score` one time.

I came accross `classification_report` of sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html.

However, it does not support `cross_val_score`. I am wondering if there is a way to do this in sklearn.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

### EDIT:

I tried to do this as suggested by @t_e_o. However, the results it produced is wrong. For instance consider the iris dataset.

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

from sklearn.model_selection cross_val_score, cross_validate
cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = ('accuracy'))
```

The results I got are as follows.

```
#cross_val_score
array([0.53333333, 0.73333333, 0.66666667, 0.8       , 0.73333333,
       0.6       , 0.86666667, 0.86666667, 0.6       , 0.8       ])
#cross_validate
{'fit_time': array([0.01695228, 0.01396275, 0.01296329, 0.01496124, 0.0149579 ,
        0.01097107, 0.01395988, 0.01495957, 0.01396394, 0.0149579 ]),
 'score_time': array([0.00199723, 0.00199652, 0.00199461, 0.00199294, 0.00199652,
        0.00199389, 0.00199485, 0.00199366, 0.00099611, 0.00099897]),
 'test_score': array([0.53333333, 0.73333333, 0.66666667, 0.8       , 0.73333333,
        0.6       , 0.86666667, 0.86666667, 0.6       , 0.8       ]),
 'train_score': array([0.94074074, 0.91851852, 0.92592593, 0.93333333, 0.91851852,
        0.91851852, 0.91111111, 0.8962963 , 0.91851852, 0.91851852])}
```

Comment: You're getting the correct results. The "test_score" of cross_validate function is same as that of cross_val_score, which is test score. "cross_validate" function is used for multi scoring, as explained in this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html . There is no other way. To find the list of metrics, have a look at sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti Thank you for the comment. what does train_score means? Is that the results we get for training data? If so, does this results show overfitting? :)

Comment: As you know, in cross validation the data X is split into training and validation set multiple times, in rotation.The model is trained using training data and its accuracy is tested using validation data. However, you can test the model against training data as well, which is "train_score" here. This may give you some insight. Eg, You're getting high mismatch between test_score and train_score because your data is not shuffled. Once shuffled, the class will be equally distributed among training and validation sets, hence the scores will be closer.

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti Thank you for your useful comment. Do you mean `stratified cross validation` by shuffle? Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of the `cross_validate` function? It might be the right option for you, so you can calculate multiple values. Example:

```
>>> scores = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3,
     ...                         scoring=('r2', 'neg_mean_squared_error'),
      ...                         return_train_score=True)
>>> print(scores['test_neg_mean_squared_error'])
    [-3635.5... -3573.3... -6114.7...]
>>> print(scores['train_r2'])
    [0.28010158 0.39088426 0.22784852]
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate

I hope it is a good solution for you!

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. I tried the following code `scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring=("accuracy", "f1_weighted"))` and compared the results with `cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'accuracy')`. However, the results I get is totally different. Do you know why this happens? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: How different are they? Usually during the cross validation process the samples for each fold are chosen randomly and thus you get different results.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782243/how-to-use-cross-val-score-with-random-state

Comment: it is very different. Please see my edits for the comparison. You will understand what I am saying :)

Comment: The results are correct. "test_score" of cross_validate function matches with that  cross_val_score. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across a similar issue, and I couldn't find an optimal solution so I've simply used a dictionary to address this. In your case I think you should be looking at something like:

```
metrics = {'precision_weighted':[],'recall_weighted':[],'f1_weighted':[],'accuracy':[]}
for i in metrics:
   metrics[i].append(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. However, in your solution (same as mine) I need to perform `cross_val_predict` mutiple times. The problem is that my dataset is really big and takes about 1 hour to run it one time. So, if I were to get 5 measures it takes 5 hours in total. Please let me know if you found a good way to solve this :)

Comment: Sklearn documentations states "Similar to cross_validate but only a single metric is permitted.". As for the time I'm waiting until saturday for my Elmo to finish! If I come across a solution, I'll make sure to let you know! Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. sure please do so, if you found a good solution. Happy coding :)